# Internal soundcard doesn't automatically switch to headphones when I plug them in

Tags: release-loki, sound

I'm having this small issue with Loki on an Asus E402S laptop:

the internal soundcard works fine and also do the headphones if I manually choose them as an output with `pavucontrol`, but when I plug or unplug the headphones jack it doesn't automatically switch between headphones and laptop speaker.

Any advice for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to have elementary OS auto switch to my bluetooth headphones by loading a extra module:

Add the following line to: `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Sources:

- https://sandalov.org/blog/2146/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/8409/autoconnecting-bluetooth-devices

Maybe there is a similar trick for regular headphones?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that it's like that by default in elementary.

Whenever, I connect my bluetooth speakers or headphones, I have to change output in sound settings.

Comment: I also think sound is managed in this way by default. I assume this is a purposeful design. I find it to be a non issue and it is the same way in my Windows machine.